# Getting minutes from string via regex

Tags: python, regex

I have task to be done. I have test file for it which is containing code:

```
import unittest
from Task302 import extract_minutes

class Task302Test(unittest.TestCase):
    """Testy do zadania 302"""

    def test_simple(self):
        """Prosty test."""
        self.assertEqual(extract_minutes("9:13"), "13")
        self.assertEqual(extract_minutes("18:44"), "44")
        self.assertEqual(extract_minutes("23:59"), "59")
        self.assertEqual(extract_minutes("0:00"), "00")
        self.assertEqual(extract_minutes("25:14"), "<NONE>")
        self.assertEqual(extract_minutes("9:61"), "<NONE>")
        self.assertEqual(extract_minutes("x9:13y"), "<NONE>")
```

I have written code:

```
def extract_minutes(string):
    pattern = '[0-1]*[0-9]+|2[0-3]:([0-5][0-9])'
    r = re.compile(pattern)
    m = r.search(string)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return "<NONE>"
```

Please explain me what is wrong with my code and how to fix it.

Comment: Please explain to us as to what errors are there so that we can explain to you what is wrong with your code

Comment: code is returning 'None' with argument "9:13"

Comment: @Cris because this `2[0-3]:([0-5][0-9])` part of your regex won't match the starting `9` . That's what i explained.

Comment: how to make or operator (|) local? ([0-1]*[0-9])+|(2[0-3]), but without parentheses that will make values avaible by group method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `|` operator only for the hours. Your regex `[0-1]*[0-9]+|2[0-3]:([0-5][0-9])` considers the hours from 0 to 19 as separate part and hours from 20 to 23 plus the minutes as separate part. And also i suggest you to put `?` instead of `*` because `*` will match the previous token zero or more times, where the `?` (except as a non-greedy quantifier) will match the previous token 0 or 1 times. And you must need to remove the `+` after the character class `[0-9]` because `+` matches the previous token one or more times.

```
pattern = r'\b(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])\b'
```

`\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. Without word boundaries, it would match this `x9:13y` string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tU2uY0/1)

Comment: yeah, you got it, i will check it more in details, because i hae more tasks. thank you